# Select an input after its inserted using `Ember.run`

Tags: ember.js

**Updated** — The problem with my solution below was with if statement around Ember.run. Removing it solved the problem, but my approach was also incorrect. Instead of scheduling the focus for after rendering, I should make a custom component as acorncom suggested.

**Original Question:**

I'm building a list of text inputs based on an array on my model. On newline I'd like to insert a new text field and then select it. I'm trying to do this with `Ember.run.scheduleOnce`, but the function I provide is never called.

I've reopened the textfield to expose a `data-index` attribute binding, and in my template am rendering:

```
{{#each model.entries as |entry index|}}
  {{input value=entry.text class='field--entry' data-index=index insert-newline=(action 'insertEntry' index)}}
{{/each}}
```

In my controller:

```
actions: {
  insertEntry(index){
    // This works fine and a new textfield is added.
    this.get('model.entries').addObject({text: 'Example'});

    if (index){ 
      Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function(){
        // This doesn't seem to work at all. 
        console.log("This is never logged");
        $(".field--entry[data-index='" + index + 1 + "']").focus();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per a work-in-progress branch here (https://github.com/ember-best-practices/recommendations/blob/initial-pass/guides/run.md), you generally want to steer clear of using `afterRender` if there are other approaches that would work better.

I'd suggest using a component to handle rendering your list of items, as you'd be able to use the  component lifecycle hooks to do what you're after. If you check the guides (specifically the section discussing `didRender`), you'll see an example that closely matches what you're after ... https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_making-updates-to-the-rendered-dom-with-code-didrender-code

Comment: That makes sense, but then I need to use a custom component.

Comment: I do think this is the technically correct answer for my use-case, however.

Comment: Yes, that's correct on the custom component front. But that's what they are for :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to manually manipulate the focus:
This Ember can set the autofocus attritbute on render.
"(eq index 0)" sets it to true on the first element only

```
{{#each model.entries as |entry index|}}
  {{input value=entry.text autofocus=(eq index 0)}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Ok I answered poorly:
But here is a working example for it @arbles:
https://ember-twiddle.com/c59e5d91d1517f298ba48098d477c1f7?openFiles=components.my-test.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-test.hbs

Answer (score 0):

There was a syntactic mistake in your template and I fixed it. I suspect that in your case the action was never called somehow. Can you check the [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/59c0c9e0e8d34310caeaddeb5ffeaede?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C) I prepared for you? What it does is simply adding a new `input` and giving focus to it. I just changed the selection logic for jquery focusing to

```
Ember.$(`.field--entry:eq(${index+1})`).focus();
```

and it simply works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, but the action is being called, as the new item is being created, the problem is with the Ember.run portion

Comment: i did not get your problem. you said `Ember.run` is not working; but it is. can you explain what your question is.

Comment: I think the problem was with the `if` block I had around `Ember.run` — I included it to check for when I call the helper without an index, but it seems to have always evaled false. Numbers are truthy, so I'm a bit confused by that.

Comment: i am also confused about your case. so your problem is gone now or does it still exist? your original question was lacking `if index` check.